# TCL: using a namespace name variable

Tags: variables, namespaces, tcl

I create a namespace where the name is contained in one variable:

```
set fg_path fg_$path
namespace eval $fg_path {
    variable Elem 17
    puts "--> [namespace current]"
}
```

But I am not able to access the Elem value or to set it, for example this doesn't works:
`set ::$fg_path::Elem [dict create]`

Thanks for any suggestion.
John

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when assembling the qualified variable name:

```
set ::${fg_path}::Elem [dict create]
```

Note the curly braces `{` and `}` which protect the variable `fg_path` for variable substitution. Without them, you would ask Tcl to run substitution for a variable named `fg_path::Elem`.

Answer (score 0):

Compound names (and other mis-parses) are when you use braces around variable names. `set ::${fg_path}::Elem [dict create]`

But if you're working in a procedure, please use `namespace upvar` instead:

```
proc set_elem {fg_path to} {
    namespace upvar $fg_path Elem vbl
    set vbl $to
}

set_elem $fg_path [dict create]
```

It's a bit long-winded for this exact case, but it's very good in longer, real code.